# Issue with SQL Server mirroring endpoint creation using SQL Server authentication

Tags: sql, sql-server, endpoint, mirroring

I am trying to create an endpoint in SQL Server 2019 using T-SQL:

```
CREATE ENDPOINT endpoint_mirroring
    STATE = STARTED AS TCP ( LISTENER_PORT = 5022 )
    FOR DATABASE_MIRRORING
    ( AUTHENTICATION = WINDOWS NEGOTIATE,
      ENCRYPTION = SUPPORTED,
      ROLE=ALL);

GO
```

I want to use SQL Server authentication for creation of mirroring endpoints. I can use SQL Server Management Studio to do that, but could not find any examples on SQL Server authentication method for T-SQL.

Thanks

Comment: Does the above code not work?

Comment: I am trying to use SQL auth

Answer (score 1):

**[As documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/the-database-mirroring-endpoint-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#EndpointAuthenticationTypes), it is not supported to use SQL Authentication for `ENDPOINT`,** there is also [no syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-endpoint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for it.

> - If every server instance is running under a domain service account, you can use Windows Authentication for your database mirroring endpoints.....
> - If any server instance is running under a built-in account, such as Local System, Local Service, or Network Service, or a nondomain account, you must use certificates for endpoint authentication....

So if you cannot use Windows Authentication, then I suggest you use Certificates. This is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/database-mirroring/use-certificates-for-a-database-mirroring-endpoint-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).